# Помогите определить cms

Tags: cms, админка

Не могу определить CMS у сайта. Вот его админка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Любая. Может вообще быть что-то самописное. Чисто по интерфейсу определить cms невозможно.

Comment: Да, это действительно самописный сайт.

Answer (score 1):

CMS - Mousewheel JS; 
Web Server - Nginx 1.6.2; 
JavaScriptFrameworks - jQuery 1.10.2, Jquery Easing; 
Analytics - Google Analytics Ukraine, Yandex.Metrika; 
Backend language - PHP 5.3.3. 
Достаточно? Установите дополнение для браузера Whatruns и будет счастье...

Comment: Mousewheel - это всего лишь jquery плагин. Назвать его cms - громко сказано, в остальном - зачёт. Сайт самописный

Comment: @Александр, я понимаю, просто процитировал выдачу Whatruns)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего самописное. Посмотрел сайт на сервисе определения CMS, https://2ip.ru/cms/ , нет ни одного признака популярных CMS.

Comment: Вы что, серьезно доверяете этому унылому сервису? Да он врет на ровном месте, не стоит ему доверять. Случай не из первых, написано с нуля, а говорит, что мол признаки вордпреса и модыкса. Что вообще не разу там не используется.